# How to share EntityModel between write and read in CQRS akka peristence

Tags: akka, cqrs, akka-persistence

I'm trying out Akka persistence with CQRS in mind.
On my Write side, I've the entity like

```
case class Evt(data:String)
```

My persist code looks like

```
persist(Evt(s"${data}"))
```

All works on the write side.

I'm using Redis journal plugin.

When I attempt to read the journal entry on the Read side, its looking for the class WriteModel.Evt and seeing below error

```
[akka.dispatch.Dispatcher] WriteModel.Evt java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WriteModel.Evt
```

Am I persisting the event appropriately?

What is the best practice to share the contact between Write and Read/Aggregator side ?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to decide what serialization format/protocol to use.

Akka persistence works out-of-box with Java serialization, which is good for a fast prove of concept but not for production systems. You could chose from protobuf, avro and even json. The are plenty of serialization protocols to chose from. Check [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence-schema-evolution.html#picking-the-right-serialization-format) out.

Depending on this, you make your choice how to share the schemas in case of protobuf or avro.

Additionally, you have to implement your own event serializer or use [default](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence-schema-evolution.html#provided-default-serializers) serializer. And consider how to manage future [event schema evolution](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence-schema-evolution.html#schema-evolution-in-event-sourced-systems).

All of this eventually dictates how to share and manage your event schema.